# Minor error in FAQ for data.SE

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, data-explorer, languages

On the [FAQ page for data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq); one of the question (with its answer) is:

> ### Which sites are included?
>
> All public Stack Exchange websites are included. Sites that are in
> public or private beta are excluded.

The error is in the phrase: "*Sites that are in public*" as it should instead have been "**Sites that are *not* in public**". Alternatively, the answer can be rephrased as:

> ### Which sites are included?
>
> All public Stack Exchange websites are included. Sites that are private beta
> or **not** public are excluded.

Comment: It should be parsed as `sites that are in (public || private) beta`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Noooo... The current FAQ is correct. All beta sites which are either private or public are excluded. That means public beta sites like [Sports.SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) are not included in the [DATA.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)